# compare first column of two altenative lines and if match then check which value is greater in column 2 of two lines and print max one line using awk

Tags: awk

Input:

```
anil 14
anil 25
umar 78
umar 13
umar 06 
amritha 06
amritha 25
amritha 17
```

Output:

```
anil 25
umar 78
amritha 25
```

How to get this output using single awk command? Please help me regards this.

Comment: Its unclear how you get your output, and also you have not posted what you have tried. (I guess that gives you the minus votes)

Answer (score 0):

If you like the largest value, try this `awk`

```
awk '{a[$1]=$2>a[$1]?$2:a[$1]} END {for (i in a) print i,a[i]}' file
amritha 25
umar 78
anil 25
```

Answer (score 0):

You could let `sort` do the sorting and then let `awk` do the picking:

```
sort -r -k 1,1 -k 2,2  file | awk '{if($1!=prev){prev=$1;print $0}}'
```

So, that says... sort by name first, then by the second column and reverse the order so that the biggest of each name comes first. Then pass that to `awk` and print the line if the first column has changed relative to the previously seen one.